# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" при объявление через функцию в vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Присваиваю в data переменную и затем обращаюсь к этой переменной ниже для получения определенного элемента из массива, но возвращается ошибка: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). Если смотреть в Dev Tools, то там undefined. Но если смотреть чистый переменную-массив(doughList) в DevTools без обращения к определенному элементу, то показывает массив, но если я хочу написать this.doughList[0].value. то падает ошибка выше. При этом в Nuxt такой вариант работает...
И если объявить в data до return, то в последующем использовании все хорошо работает (пример если использовать normalizeSize переменную). Если делать через computed, то ошибка та же самая. Из json приходят обычный массив. Функция normalizeSizes() они немного изменяют массив и все.

````
import { dough, sizes, sauces, ingredients } from "@/static/pizza.json";

export default {
  name: "Index",
  components: {
    BuilderSizeSelector,
    BuilderIngredientsSelector,
    BuilderDoughSelector,
    BuilderPizzaView,
  },

  data() {
    const normalizeSize = normalizeSizes(sizes);
    const normalizeSauce = normalizeSauces(sauces);
    return {
      doughList: dough,
      sizeList: normalizeSize,
      sauceList: normalizeSauce,
      ingredientList: normalizeIngredients(ingredients),
      namePizza: "",
      currentDough: this.doughList[0].value,
      currentSize: normalizeSize[1].value,
      currentSauce: normalizeSauce[0].value,
    };
  },
}, ```
````

Comment: Vue с ума сходит от такого, заверните ваши нормалайзы в computed

Comment: Как я писал выше, что и в computed не работает, то же самое. Работает только так, как в примере выше. Если указать в data до return

Comment: ```currentDough: this.doughList[0].value,``` - функция data() ещё ничего не успела вернуть, а вы пытаетесь уже что-то получить. Надо так: ```currentDough: dough[0].value,``` К ```this.doughList``` можно обращаться только после того, как функция data() завершит работу.